# How to return multiple phone numbers from the same string?

Tags: regex, r

I'm starting to learn how to use regular expressions to parse information from text.  I've been able to write an expression in R to pull a phone number from a string based on the different variations I see in my text file.

```
reg_expr <- "\\(?1?\\s?-?\\(?\\d{3})?\\s?-?\\d{3}\\s?-?\\d{4})?"  
data[, Phone := str_extract(Text, reg_expr)]
```

But I don't know how to modify this to return 2 phone numbers from the same text string.  For instance:

*"Hi, please call 123-456-7890, or for faster service 1-800-987-6543."*

So if my first column in my data table is the text string, the second column (Phone) would show 123-456-7890.  But I miss out on the second phone number offered.

**Is there a way to return both numbers?**  Ideally, it would place them both together in the Phone column like, 123-456-7890, 1-800-987-6543.

My only idea was to put curly braces at the end of the regular expression, but it didn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the str_extract_all function in the stringr package.

```
str_extract_all("Hi, please call 123-456-7890, or for faster service 1-800-987-6543.", reg_expr)
[1] " 123-456-7890"  "1-800-987-6543"
```

Comment: I was so focused on the regular expression portion of the problem I totally missed this function!  The list output makes it a little difficult to work with, but works!